# How to use Unions when creating Input types, Mutations in nest graphql schema, by code first approach

Tags: nestjs, typegraphql

I am doing code-first approach in typescript for a class (`MyClass`) that contains Union as one of the attribute types. I used `@ObjectType()` and `@InputType()` , `@Field(type => myUnion)` decorators.

I defined a graphql type for `myUnion` using `createUnionType` from https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/unions-and-enums. When schema.gql is autogenerated, I see type for `myUnion`, MyClass but not input for `MyClass`. Is there a way to create Input Types and Mutations for a class with union types using nest-graphql ?

Note: I have no issues, with `ObjectType()` or `Query()`, but input types are not getting generated.

What is the best way to use unions.

Answer (score 3):

As I just answered in the [Discord](https://discord.com/channels/520622812742811698/520649487924985885/815305737877061652), it's not possible.

> Input Unions still seem to not be a thing in GraphQL: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/issues/488 There's an RFC for it: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/blob/main/rfcs/InputUnion.md and an open pull request here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/733 (opened last June)

Comment: still not avalaible. The current proposal is here: https://github.com/graphql/graphql-spec/pull/825

Comment: Is there at least a workaround? How people usually tackle this issue?